# php not working properly in mail()

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send the information as a mail to the admin
Below is the mail code and I am reading this using file_get_contents() in another file.

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
require_once("mysqlconnect.php");
session_start();
?>

<html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mail.css">
   </head>
   <body>
    <table border="2">
    <?php
        $q="select * from profile where mobile=2147483647";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         {
             foreach($row as $key=>$value)
             {
                 if($key=="Email")
                    echo"<tr><th>$key</th><td><a href='mailto:$value;           target='_blank'>$value</td></tr>";
                else
                    echo"<tr><th>".str_replace('_',' ',$key)."</th>         <td>$value</td></tr>";
             }
         }
    ?>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  session_destroy();
?>
```

The result of this code in the mail is the PHP code itself..

```
$value) { if($key=="Email") echo"
$key    $value
"; else echo"
".str_replace('_',' ',$key)."   $value
"; } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` literally reads in a file as a string. If you're reading in a PHP file using that method, it'll literally return the code, which is what you're getting.

If you want to send HTML as an e-mail, use something like a template system ([sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines/)) or build a string and pass it onto the `mail()` function.

[PHP documentation: file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in reg.php on adding this as string to the other file...

Comment: @KratiChaturvedi you can upvote answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

file_get_contents returns the content of a file as string. It does not executes the code inside it.

To use the HTML from a php file you can use php's buffer.

Like this:

```
ob_start();

include('file_path_here');

$HTML = ob_get_clean();
```

This will store the output of the file in the `$HTML` variable.